# Closing the tab in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I created the new tab through addin and added it to the repository through Repository.AddTab but using  this API opens/Activates the tab but I want to open the tab only when it is required so for that I used Repository.ActivateTab.So is there any API to close the Tab in EA.

Comment: Downvoted: shows no research effort. At SO, you should ask questions about problems you've encountered when you've tried something, not generic introductory questions about a topic because those are not likely to be useful to anyone else. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Uffe  Hmm. Sounds a bit too picky. EA often forces one to take unexpected paths. I also don't know how to close such a tab, but a Windozer might know a way around EA's API.

Answer (score 1):

There is an operation `EA.Repository.RemoveTab(string tabname)` that for some reason is not documented in the help file.

I just found it by searching the [forum](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,4926.msg122699.html#msg122699)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for this little gem.